# PHP code not returning response from other site

Tags: php, http

I am using 000webhosting.com. I have uploaded a file check.php

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.otherdomain.com/login/?';
    $data = array('user' => 'admin',
                  'pass' => 'password');

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }
var_dump($result);
?>
```

When i call www.000webhosting.com/check.php, it returns `string(0) ""`

Whereas , when i upload check.php in allcodez.com and call www.allcodez.com/check.php, it returns `{"status":"true", "login":"true"}`.

Is the problem with 000webhosting.com settings? or any other?

Comment: `000webhosting.com` looks like a dead domain, and `www.000webhosting.com/check.php` brings up the same as the front page.

Comment: well, not dead, but definitely a placeholder/squatter site.

Comment: Oops Sorry. It's 000webhost.com and by the way.. i am using through a subdomain.. so, it will be mysubdomain.000webhost.com